# Replace last 4 digits by adding 1 digit (excluding 0x)

Tags: linux, function, awk, replace, substring

I have the following file (test.txt) which I want to change the logic as following:

```
0 becomes 1
1 becomes 2 
2 becomes 3 
3 becomes 4
4 becomes 5
5 becomes 6 
6 becomes 7 
7 becomes 8 
8 becomes 9
9 becomes 0

$ cat test.txt
69|1074330570|1,sip:+121345633210x3Bverstat=TN-Validation-Passed|tel:+12134565534|0
69|1077822111|2,;tel:+12223120011~sip:+12223120051@vzpps.com;|sip:+13123120022@vzpps.com|0
```

I want to change the last 4 digits but when x is next to 0x, then 0 does not count.
For Example:
In The First Line '+121345633210x', last 4 are 3321.
In The Second Line, '+12223120011', last 4 are 0011 and '+12223120051', last 4 are 0051
The output should look as following:

```
69|1074330570|1,sip:+121345644320x3Bverstat=TN-Validation-Passed|tel:+12134566645|0
69|1077822111|2,;tel:+12223121122~sip:+12223121162@vzpps.com;|sip:+13123121133@vzpps.com|0
```

It needs to exclude '+1' and then count '10' digits in which I want to replace last 4 in the third and fourth columns.

```
121345633210 becomes 121345644320 / 12134565534 becomes 12134566645
12223120011  becomes 12223121122  / 12223120051 becomes 12223121162 / 13123120022 becomes 13123121133
```

I used the below logic when the column is just a number. But in this case, it has other stuff so below logic is not working but is correct to convert numbers by adding 1 digit.

```
awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" '
NR>0 {                                                      
    for (i=3;i<=4;i++) {                                   
        str = substr($i, 1, length($i) - 4)                 
        for (j = length($i) - 3; j <= length($i); j++) {    
            str = str (substr($i, j, 1) + 1) % 10           
        }
        $i = str                                            
    }
} 
1'
```

Comment: as pointed out by the various answers you received to your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77481565), after splitting the fields based on '|` you need to further parse the 3rd/4th fields (eg, split on `+`, use a regex) to obtain the phone number; your current code doesn't make any attempt to parse out the phone number from the 3rd/4th fields; hint: after `str = substr(...)` add `print $i,str` to see what's in the `$i` field and the `str` variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumptions:

- a `+` only shows up in the 3rd/4th fields and then only at the front of a phone number

One `awk` approach:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="+" }                               # split input on "+"
      { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {                    # loop through fields that start with a phone number
            oldfld = $i                            # save current field
            $i = ""                                # initialize new field
            d1 = substr(oldfld,1,1)                # get 1st digit
            len = (d1 == 1 ? 7 : 6)                # determine length of phone prefix
            $i = substr(oldfld,1,len)              # save everything up to the phone prefix

            for (j=(len+1); j<=(len+4); j++) {     # loop through last 4 digits of phone number
                x = substr(oldfld,j,1)             # get current digit
                $i = $i (x==9 ? 0 : x+1)           # increment and add to new field
            }

            $i = $i substr(oldfld,len+4+1)         # save rest of old field
         }
      }
1                                                  # print current line
' test.txt
```

This generates:

```
69|1074330570|1,sip:+121345644320x3Bverstat=TN-Validation-Passed|tel:+12134566645|0
69|1077822111|2,;tel:+12223121122~sip:+12223121162@vzpps.com;|sip:+13123121133@vzpps.com|0
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `gnu-awk`, you can do this:

```bash
awk '
function repl(s,  i, r, ch) {
   for (i=1; i<=length(s); ++i) {
      ch = substr(s,i,1)
      r = r (ch == 9 ? 0 : ch+1)
   }
   return r
}
BEGIN {FS=OFS="+"}
{
   for (j=2; j<=NF; ++j) {
      if (match($j, /^([0-9]+)([0-9]{4})(0x|[^x0-9]|$)(.*)/, a))
         $j = a[1] repl(a[2]) a[3] a[4]
   }
} 1' file

69|1074330570|1,sip:+121345644320x3Bverstat=TN-Validation-Passed|tel:+12134566645|0
67|1077822111|2,;tel:+12223121122~sip:+12223121162@vzpps.com;|sip:+13123121133@vzpps.com|0
```

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk '{
    head = ""
    while ( match($0,/([^+]+\+[0-9]{7})([0-9]{4})/,a) ) {
        digs = ""
        for ( i=1; i<=4; i++ ) {
            digs = digs ((substr(a[2],i,1) + 1) % 10)
        }
        head = head a[1] digs
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print head $0
}' test.txt
69|1074330570|1,sip:+121345644320x3Bverstat=TN-Validation-Passed|tel:+12134566645|0
69|1077822111|2,;tel:+12223121122~sip:+12223121162@vzpps.com;|sip:+13123121133@vzpps.com|0
```

That produces the expected output without testing for just the 3rd or 4th fields and without testing for `0x` because there are no strings in fields other than 3 or 4 that match the target regexp, and though you said to ignore `0` followed by `x`, in reality you're simply always changing the first 11 digits and any `0` that's followed by `x` is the 12th digit.

You could do the same using any POSIX awk with:

```
awk '{
    head = ""
    while ( match($0,/\+[0-9]{11}/) ) {
        digs = ""
        for ( i=1; i<=4; i++ ) {
            digs = digs ((substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH-5+i,1) + 1) % 10)
        }
        head = head substr($0,1,RSTART+RLENGTH-5) digs
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print head $0
}' test.txt
```